# How to write a redis client with c++ Builder

Tags: redis, c++builder

Does someone have experience in writing a redis client with c++ Builder?

I tried several redis Clients listened on redis.io but I was not able to get any of them compiling with C++-Builder.

Comment: It would help if you would explain what problems you are having with compiling, what version of C++Builder you are using, whether you are using the legacy Borland compiler or the newer CLang compiler, etc.  If you can't get any of the C/C++ clients to compile, you might consider trying to compile the [Delphi client](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphiredisclient), since C++Builder includes a Delphi compiler and shares RTL/VCL runtime libraries with Delphi. You can use Delphi source code in C++ projects (but not the other way around).

Comment: Or, you could try your hand at using any popular C++Builder compatible TCP library to implement the [REDIS protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) in your own code. For instance, [Indy](http://www.indyprojct.org) ships with C++Builder and could easily be used to implement a custom REDIS client using its `TIdTCPClient` component and a little code logic.

Comment: The [Delphi Redis client](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphiredisclient) I linked to earlier is [now available in Embarcadero's GetIt Package Manager](http://www.danieleteti.it/delphi-redis-client-available-through-getit-package-manager/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Using the CLang Compiler solved my problem. Thx.